# How to obtain Container.DataItem from parent control?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, repeater, itemtemplate, templatefield

Suppose that I create an ASP.net repeater.  Suppose further that I put an ASP.net GridView in the ASP.net repeater's ItemTemplate.

Suppose that it looks like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat='server' id='myRepeater'>

<ItemTemplate>
<%# "This Repeater DataSource is " + Container.DataItem.ToString() %>

 <asp:GridView runat='server' id='repeaterGridView'>
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
   <% // I would like to refer to the Repeater Data Source here, but I only know
      // how to refer to the GridView Data Source here.
   <ItemTemplate>
   </asp:templateField>
 </Columns>
 </asp:Repeater>

</ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

I would like to refer to the Repeater DataSource inside a TemplateField for the GridView.  How can I do this?

Comment: So are you binding some sort of an integer array (or something similar to a single column datatable) to the repeater?

Answer (score 0):

Container refers to the TemplateField, so try calling

```
((RepeaterItem)Container.NamingContainer.NamingContainer).DataSource
```